# jms-message-bus sample not working

Tags: spring-xd

I have tried to follow the steps in 
https://github.com/SpringOne2GX-2014/Spring-XD-Internals/tree/master/jms-message-bus to point to an external Active MQ.

But when i start the XD with `./xd-singlenode --transport jms`
I'm getting an error, i think JMS is not getting recognized provided in the Wiki, what am i missing?
Below is the error

```
`2015-02-11 16:29:42,708 1.1.0.RELEASE  INFO main` 
server.SingleNodeApplication - Started SingleNodeApplication in    
0.963 seconds (JVM running for 1.313)
'jms' is not a valid value for option --transport. 
Possible values are [rabbit, redis, kafka, local]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repo was written for a talk we presented at SpringOne2GX 2014, in September and has not been updated to work with Spring XD 1.1. It should work with the 1.0.4 release but it is intended as a simple prototype to illustrate how Spring XD supports pluggable transports (as of Sep 2014 anyway).

In Spring XD 1.1, the message bus implementations are not statically included in the classpath and the jars must be installed in $XD_INSTALL_DIR/xd/lib/messagebus/. Note that the --transport option value is validated by searching this directory which is why you are seeing the error. The configured transport's MessageBus implementation is loaded "on the fly" when the server starts. It's possible that this will work as described if you install the jar under xd/lib/messagebus/jms but I haven't tried it. Additionally, this prototype starts an embedded activemq broker and will need some modification to point to an external Active MQ broker, as suggested in your question.

Comment: Excellent - Had to make few tweaks on the packaging though,  1) Need a folder under the messagebus, i called it jms-bus 2)  the *.xml files  need to be present under META-INF/spring-xd/bus.   And it was able to connect to external ActiveMQ with ease. Great work !!!  Thanks David