# spring-xd jms-message-bus with jms sink

Tags: spring-jms, spring-xd

I tried to create a sink module similar to the source. Changed the configuration so it will use an jms outbound adaptor to send out to a queue. 
Is there an easy way to say- since its already using jms-transport just send the output to some output.queue using the same transport?

Im getting this error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:181)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:315)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:178)
```

#### See also

> [jms-message-bus sample not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465913/jms-message-bus-sample-not-working) which covers previous work attempting to create the `jms` message bus

The sink/jms-out/lib:

```
activemq-all-5.7.0.jar
activemq-client-5.10.0.jar
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
hawtbuf-1.10.jar
spring-integration-jms-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
```

sink/jms-out/config:

```
<import resource="../../../common/jms-activemq-infrastructure-context.xml"/>

<int:channel id="input" />

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut"
    destination-name="xd.bus.output"
    channel="input" 
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
```

These are the contents in the message bus:

```
activemq-all-5.7.0.jar
jms-message-bus-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
spring-integration-jms-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
xbean-spring-3.7.jar
```

Comment: Could you provide a listing of your `$XD_HOME/lib/messagebus/jms` as well as your jms sink lib (`$XD_HOME/modules/sink/jms/lib`) ?

Comment: Do you want the list of jars in the lib folder or the contents of the *.xml files in config.  Thanks for looking

Comment: Any luck or is it a big change. Thanks

Comment: Seems like a pretty nasty bug. I'd recommend moving everything that may be shared in the `$XD_HOME/lib` folder for now. I've created https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2754 to track the issue

Comment: Oops.  just gave a shot by just taking out the activeMq*.jar from that lib folder, it doesn't like it  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
 at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parseBeanFromExtensionElement(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:282)

Comment: Good luck though, i will watch the Jira